# How do I stop a function from continuing in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What do I need to do to make a function that stops another function from continuing?
Specifically what's going on here is; the start button starts an animation to change the width of the div. When I click the div, how can I stop the animation from continuing?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function start() {
        $("#block").animate({width:'0px'},2000);
    }
    function stop() {
        //How do I stop the start() function from continuing?
    }
</script>
<style>
    #block {
        height:150px;
        width:150px;
        background-color: blue;
    }
</style>
<div id="block" onclick="stop()></div>
<button onclick="start()">Start</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is single-threaded, a function cannot stop another function, because they cannot run at the same time.

That being said, your issue is actually a jQuery animate issue. Just use [the jQuery `stop` method](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) to tell jQuery to stop animating the element.

```
function stop() {
    $("#block").stop();
}
```

### Working Example:

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function start() {
        $("#block").animate({width:'0px'},2000);
    }
    function stop() {
        $("#block").stop();
    }
</script>
<style>
    #block {
        height:150px;
        width:150px;
        background-color: blue;
    }
</style>
<div id="block" onclick="stop()"></div>
<button onclick="start()">Start</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Stop the `.animate` rather than the `start` function. The `start` function is not actually running while the animation is taking place, it just calls the `.animate` jquery method, that's what you want to interrupt.

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 0):

Use stop function

```
 function stop() {
            $("#block").stop();
}
```

[Live Code](http://jsfiddle.net/u7ghv6ff/1/)

Comment: UM, the .animate() is wrong, but the .stop() is right.

Comment: There is no reason to call `.animate` before calling `.stop`.

Comment: ryt , was more specific

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JQuery stop() whose documentation is given [here](http://api.jquery.com/stop/).

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function start() {
        $("#block").animate({width:'0px'},2000);
    }
 function stop() {
     $("#block").stop();
    }
</script>
<style>
    #block {
        height:150px;
        width:150px;
        background-color: blue;
    }
</style>
<div id="block" onclick="stop()"></div>
<button onclick="start()">Start</button>
```